# Create a mysql temporary table with a variable number of columns

Tags: mysql, pivot, temp-tables

I'm trying to display the results of a game in a table. My raw data looks like the following:

```
matchID  StageID  StringID  ShooterID   FinalScore
118         1       3       10040       18.008
118         1       2       10040       13.639
118         1       1       10040       9.895
118         1       3       10051       15.464
118         1       2       10051       23.842
118         1       1       10051       21.018
118         1       3       10041       13.601
118         1       2       10041       8.151
118         2       1       10041       49.5
118         2       2       10041       59.5
118         2       3       10041       49.5
118         2       1       10040       69.5
118         2       3       10040       39.5
118         2       1       10051       109.5
118         2       2       10051       89.5
118         2       3       10051       99.5
118         2       2       10040       59.5
... many more rows with a variable number of StageID's
```

The output table should look like the following:

```
ShooterID   Stage1  Stage2  Total
10039       38.26   188.50  226.76
10040       41.54   168.50  210.04
10041       28.33   158.50  186.83
10042       59.98   355.50  415.48
10043       49.23   198.50  247.73
10047       33.16   218.50  251.66
10048       33.21   358.50  391.71
10051       60.32   298.50  358.82
10052       30.74   278.50  309.24
10053       62.49   268.50  330.99
```

I've tried doing this with group_concat(), but things got really nasty when I tried to add the Total column.

Now I've decided to try and do this with a stored proceedure using temporary tables. My problem is that I can't figure out how to create a temporary table with a variable number of columns. I did find a similar question, but it was using MSSQL and did not work for mysql. ([Procedure to create a table with a variable number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518390/procedure-to-create-a-table-with-a-variable-number-of-columns))

I did find some examples of doing this with a static number of columns, but creating the temporary table dynamically has me stumped. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: how about not creating a table, but generating the report that you want

Comment: You are ["pivoting" "dynamically"](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/).

Comment: create a sqlfiddle with data. Kinda lazy to do it all tonite.

Comment: Sorry,  forgot to add a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8c8ba/1